# How does root cause analysis work for polinomial equations?

Tags: polynomials

Imagine you have a function $$f(A,B) =A \cdot B$$ where $A=g(t)$ and $B=h(t)$ and $g$ and $h$ are unknown.

You measure $f(A,B)$ at $t_0$ and $t_1$ and you see a difference (either positive or negative).
This implies there was a variation in $A$ and/or $B$ during instants $t_0$ and $t_1$.

How do you compute the “importance” of each of $A$, $B$ variations with regards to the variation of $f(A,B)$?

***Example 1:*** maybe $A$ relatively varied a lot between $t_0$ and $t_1$, but $B$ remained stable and $f(A,B)$ didn’t varied that much (e.g., the equation is much more sensible to variations in $B$ than in $A$).

***Example 2:*** both $A$ and $B$ varied a bit, but a minor variation in $A$ would cause a bigger variation in $f(A,B)$.

***Bonus questions:*** what if were there several polynomial terms in the equation (e.g., $f = A_1 \cdot B_1 +A_2 \cdot B_2 +A_3 \cdot B_3$)?

Comment: What assumptions on $A$ and $B$ do you have ?

Comment: Sorry, could you please expand? Examples of assumptions would help me

Comment: I guess the assumptions that you will want to add depend on your original problem (e.g. Are there physical constraints ? Where do $A$ and $B$ come from ? Continuity ? Polynomial expression ?). Because your current problem is not well conditioned, and a plethora of $A$ and $B$ will solve it.

Comment: @Guilhermevrs, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @Guilhermevrs, since the function $f(A,B)=A\!\cdot\!B$ is symmetric with respect to $A$ and $B$, it is not possible that a big variation of $A$ and a little variation of $B$ cause a little variation of $f(A,B)$. Moreover, for the sane reason, it is not possible that a little variation of $B$ and a minor variation of $A$ cause a big variation of $f(A,B)$. It means that the variations of $A$ and $B$ have the same "importance" with regards to the variation of $f(A,B)=A\!\cdot\!B$.